# 50 Hz noise only in chest leads of 12 lead ECG

Tags: noise, biopotential

I am implementing a 12-lead ECG signal conditioning circuit. With the current design the bipolar leads (lead-I and II) are of sufficient quality with no visible 50 Hz noise. However, the unipolar leads (V1-V6) have large amplitudes of 50Hz noise. Each channel has an identical signal conditioning path. The circuit is powered from a GW Instek DC power supply. The first image is the output of Lead-II and the second the ouput of V5

What could be the source of this 50Hz noise in only the unipolar leads?

[image]

Edit: Circuit Schematic added
[image]

Comment: What are we looking at in the pictures and what circuit do you have (an exact circuit diagram and not a guess nor some fritzing cartoon).

Comment: *bipolar leads ... unipolar leads* That's probably differential and single-ended in EE's language. Include a schematic so that we can be sure of this. If the "unipolar" is indeed single-ended then you can expect 50 Hz as that comes in from the mains. In a differential probe situation you can cancel out that 50 Hz signal.

Comment: It doesn't look like 50 Hz signal. I don't understand what 50 Hz noise would be.

Comment: bipolar/unipolar is a typical wording among medical scientists and physicians. Two examples of halfway comprehensible medical lingo :)

Comment: Bipolar leads are obtained by amplifying the difference between the signal directly obtained from two electrodes. The unipolar leads are obtained by amplifying the difference between the signal from one electrode and Wilson's central terminal which is a reference potential obtained by averaging the signal from 3 electrodes (Right Arm, Left Arm and Left Leg). So its still differential in nature.

Comment: This is a challenging area of signal processing. For general EE amusement, here is the state of the art, http://www.heartrhythmcongress.com/files/file/HRC2014%20Presentations/141008-Master%20Class%20EP,%20I%20Wright.pdf

Comment: @AliChen, looks li,e an OK review

Answer (score 1):

Use of the Wilson Central Terminal can cause noisy recordings.  (Stevenson, William G., and Kyoko Soejima. "Recording techniques for clinical electrophysiology." Journal of cardiovascular electrophysiology 16.9 (2005): 1017-1022.)  All biopotential amps are somewhat differential, but to get the unipolar leads, the second side is effectively ground, and so you have a lower CMRR.  It can simply come down to differential vs pseudo-differential

See also "Wan, Sunny WS, and Hung T. Nguyen. "50 Hz interference and noise in ECG recordings—A review." Aust. Phys. Eng. Sci. Med 17 (1994): 108-115."

It's also possible that your electrodes are not all well placed.  Have you tried abrading the skin lightly?  Are you using driven leg techniques, which can  reduce effective electrode impedance?  A complete diagram, including the types of electrodes you are using would be of help.

Comment: I am using a right leg drive. I am using disposable gel electrodes. I have also tried using a fresh set with no improvements in the chest leads.

Comment: Secondly, don't we use a right leg drive to reduce the electrode impedance to reduce the coupled/induced 50Hz common mode voltage across the ECG system?